# Freezer cycles to very low temp every 24 hours...is this opposite from expected?

Tags: thermostat

We expect periodic freezer warming in the defrost cycle. But my freezer does the opposite. It consistently swings low (-15) then returns to its normal variation around the target (+/- 10). So it works fine I guess, but why do I get this deep temp drop every 24 hours or so? I never have a frost problem, so whatever causes excessive frost/ice on the cooling fins is not a problem. But it seems that the defrost cycle is working in reverse. It gets cooler instead of warmer. I've replace the board twice, could i have messed something up?

GE PSS26MSTE SS[image]

Comment: Was there a reason that you replaced the board?  Does replace mean - a new board?  What time of day does it dip, and is that consistent?

Comment: What sort of degrees? If they're Celsius (as most of the world use) it's running a bit warm to start with, if Fahrenheit (in some places), a bit cold.